# Jquery doesn't display utf-8 characters while dynamically creating new element

Tags: jquery, utf-8

```
    $('<ul>').attr({

                id : 'detaylabel',
                "class": 'lab'


            }).appendTo("div#verss");
            var ull = "Yıl";
            $('<li>'+ull+'</li>').appendTo('#detaylabel');
```

in the above code I am trying to display 'Yıl' string, but I get 'Y�l'

I also set everything in the page to UTF-8.

Note: I am building JSP page and using AJAX. request, response and AJAX displaying UTF-8 correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your files too? Setting only your JSP-response tells the server to claim that it delivers UTF-8, but not to actually do that. You have to make sure that your files actually are in UTF-8 (e. g. with the context-menu in eclipse on the file and set it - check your files after this).

Do this for alle (text-)files, not only jsp, but for js/css/etc. as well.

Comment: yes I checked them again all is set to UTF-8.just jquery create element makes problem anything else displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just now; in the edit tab in eclipse through Set Encoding button I set the .js file encoding type to UTF-8 and it is ok for now.